# Conditions with GSM module SIM900 doesn't execute

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I'm executing this code to control a LED with GSM SIM900 message but there are two problems. First, it receives messages sometimes and some times doesn't. The second is that it doesn't execute the `if` conditions that are on the GSM message when received.

Is there a problem with my GSM module? Can any one help?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gsm(9,10);
String msg;
const int LED = 13;

void setup() {
  gsm.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("PUMP CONTROL");
  Serial.println("t : to receive text");
  delay(1000);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0)
  switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 't':
    showSMS();
    break;
  }

  while(gsm.available() > 0)
  {
    Serial.write(gsm.read());
  }
  if ( msg == "ON")
  {
    Serial.println("ON");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
     Serial.println("ON1");
    delay(1000);
  } else if (msg == "OFF")
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
  if(msg != "") msg = "";
}

void showSMS()
{
 gsm.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
 gsm.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
 delay(1000);
 msg = "";
 while(gsm.available() > 0)
 {
  msg += gsm.read();
 }
 Serial.println(msg);
}
```

Comment: There are some basic commands that you should run before checking the messages. Like **AT\r\n** and check network status available or not and there are some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve solved the condition problems by making the condition with the ASCII code of ON and OFF.

I replaced:

```
if ( msg == “ON”)
```

with

```
if(msg.indexOf("ON")>=0)
```

and replaced:

```
else if (msg == "OFF")
```

with

```
if(msg.indexOf("OFF")>=0)
```